# perform click via softkeyboard enter

Tags: android, interface, android-softkeyboard, enter

hm.. maybe a  little stupid question, but i dont get it on my i own...

```
    package com.example.wettkampftimerbt;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.Key;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class ServMPW extends Activity_ActivityGroup implements OnClickListener{

        Button enter, cancel;
        EditText eingabe, eingabe2, masterpw;
        String pwx, eingabex, pass, adminacchint1x, adminacchint2x;
    private final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs";  
    private final String PREFS_PW = "pw";
    private final String PREFS_lang = "lang";
    private final String TITLE5 = "title5";
    private final String ADMINACCHINT1 = "adminacchint1";
    private final String ADMINACCHINT2 = "adminacchint2";
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.servmpw);   
     //((TextView)((FrameLayout)((LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView()).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     String title5x=(getSharedPreferences(PREFS_lang, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(TITLE5, "Administrationszugang"));
    this.setTitle(title5x);
     adminacchint1x=(getSharedPreferences(PREFS_lang, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(ADMINACCHINT1, "Passwort"));
     adminacchint2x=(getSharedPreferences(PREFS_lang, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(ADMINACCHINT2, "falsches Passwort"));

            enter=(Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
            cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            eingabe=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eingabe);
            masterpw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.masterpw);
            eingabe.setHint(adminacchint1x);
            eingabe2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.eingabe2);
            enter.setOnClickListener(this);
            cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
            public void onClick (View v){

             if (v==cancel){
                    finish();}
            else if (v == enter){
                entermeth();
            }   

                    else {
                eingabe.setText("");
                eingabe.setHint(adminacchint2x);}}



public void OnKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode==66)
        entermeth();
}
public void entermeth(){

    eingabe2.setText(getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREFS_PW, "bbb"));  
    pwx = eingabe2.getText().toString();
    Log.e("pw", PREFS_PW + "." + pwx);
    eingabex = eingabe.getText().toString(); 
    masterpw.setText("aaa");
    String masterpwx = masterpw.getText().toString();
    Log.e("pw:", masterpwx);
    if (eingabex.equals(pwx)||(eingabex.equals(masterpwx))){
        Intent admin = new Intent (ServMPW.this, Admin.class);
        ServMPW.this.finish();
        startActivity(admin);}


}
}
```

I want to perform the click on my own enterbutton, if the enter button on the softkeyboard is pressed. But it doesnt work... What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing is ever calling the `OnKey` method. That's what u missed.
Also, it's not a good programming practice to force clicks. You should instead create a method `private doEnterActions(){ }` and on both enter key and enter button u just call that method.

edit:

just like you setClickListener to your button (implemented by the activity) you have to make the activity implement, and set as listeners for the key events. That is done using `enter.setOnKeyListener()`

Comment: okay, sepreate enter method.. checked ^^ but how/when to call OnKey?

Comment: sorry, my answer was a bit incomplete. I'll edit it to add more info.

Comment: created entermeth() no more clickforcing ^^

Comment: edited. you can use the OnKeyListener, also explore the EditText listeners options, others might interest you, as in AndroidVogue answer

Comment: still a little dazzeled... my button is called enter too, so `enter.setOnKeyListener()` wouldnt work i cause of rename so how do i call him now?

Comment: sorry again, it's for those `EditText eingabe, eingabe2, masterpw;` whichever u want to capture.

Comment: okay, now i added `eingabe.setOnKeyListener` and he wants me to set a `(l)` what is this for? Pls excuse my point´-to-point questioning... im in a bad mood today, so my concentration stayed at home it seems...

Comment: it's just like the setOnClickListener from the button. Your activity is implementing this clicklistener, so you could just pass `this`. So you just make your activity implement the OnKeyListener too and make `eingabe.setOnKeyListener(this);`  Like this: `implements OnClickListener, OnKeyListener`

Comment: aaaaaaaaaahh... so easy -.- thx for your patience, now it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

On your `EditText` you can bind `OnEditorActionListener`. Something like this

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
       if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
           //do here your stuff here
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }
});
```